# Find the solutions of $2z^3+2z^2=4$ with one of them being 1 using the rational root theorem.

Tags: calculus, complex-numbers

I tried:

$$2z^3+2z^2=4 \Leftrightarrow\\
z^3+z^2=2 \Leftrightarrow \\
z^3+z^2-2=0\Leftrightarrow \\
???$$

I think there are two ways to solve this. One of them would be using the rational root theorem to simplify and solve this.

I tried finding the roots from the divisors:

$$\frac{\text{divisors of -2}}{\text{divisors of 1}} = \frac{\text{1,2}}{1}=\text{1,2}$$

1 is a root of the equation (as also stated in my book).

Next I tried following the step [here](https://www.symbolab.com/solver/step-by-step/z%5E%7B%5E3%7D%2Bz%5E%7B%5E2%7D-2%3D0) $$\frac{z^3+z^2-2}{z-1} = ???$$

If I could get this equation in the form $(z-1)(z^2+2z+2)$ I could easily solve it so my first question is how do I simplify $\frac{z^3+z^2-2}{z-1}$? And why is it divided by $z-1$?

Secondly, I think this can be solved by building a triangle. Since $z^3+z^2-2$ is a 3rd degree polynominal then it has 3 roots. It is also a complex number, so I can represent those roots as an equilateral triangle in the complex plane. The book gives me one solution which is $1$, so I could start building a triangle from that: 
[image]

But my book states the solutions are $-1-i$ and $-1+i$ besides from 1. What went wrong?

So basically, how do I solve this problem using the two aforementioned methods?

Comment: I'm not sure what the "rational root theorem" is, but since you know one root the natural way to proceed is to factorize the polynom: $z^3+z^2-2=(z-1)(z^2+2z+2)$ and then solve the second-degree equation $z^2+2z+2=0$... About your geometric approach, it is a smart way to handle the problem, but why do you think the triangle should be equilateral ?

Comment: @Evargalo That's what I am trying to do, but I don't know how to factorize this polynominal

Comment: @MarkRead are you familiar with synthetic division or polynomial long division?

Comment: @JohnLou I am familiar with the long division. Are they the same thing? I'll give it a try.

Comment: Synthetic division is often a little faster, but they yield the same thing. Don't forget to add a $0x$ term.

Comment: @MarkRead There is a very well-known formula to solve the quadratic polynomial $az^2+bz+c=0$: $z=\dfrac{-b\pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$. On the other hand, notice that your argument of creating an equilateral triangle is not true in general: The solutions of the polynomial $z^3-z=0$ ($z=0,-1,1$) do not form an equilateral triangle in the complex plane.

Comment: @Evargalo The Rational Root Theorem, common in high school algebra courses, states that roots of a polynomial with integer coefficients can take the form of $d_n/d_0$, where $d_n $ is a factor of $a_n$ and $d_0$ of $a_0$.

Comment: @ Sean Roberson: thank you! I often happen to ignore the english denomination of theorems...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you know that $1$ gives a solution, you know that 
$$z^3 + z^2 - 2 = (z - 1)g(z)$$
where $g(z)$ is a polynomial of degree $2$ (do you see why?). Hence this implies that 
$$g(z) = \frac{z^3 + z^2 - 2}{z-1}$$
which you can find by just doing the division or by writing $g(z) = z^2 + az + b$ (do you see why the coefficient at $z^2$ is necessairly $1$?). Doing the multiplication, you find that 
$$z^3 + z^2 - 2 = z^3 + az^2 + bz - z^2 - az - b$$
and comparing coefficients gives that 
$$\begin{cases}
1 &= a-1\\
0 &= b - a\\
-2 &= -b
\end{cases}$$
from which we find that $b = 2$ and hence $a = 2$.

The thing with the triangle works only for equations of the form $z^n = a$, since this has solutions on the circle with radius $\sqrt{a}$. This follows by looking at the moduli of both sides of this equation.